# Best way to filter out LDAP users

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I am using an LDAP - Active Directory to authenticate users for a project of mine.

I currently have 2 login pages - 1 is intended for students, the other for staff.

I have managed to write an authentication script to bind to the LDAP server - this works for all users stored on the LDAP server.

Now i want to be able to filter out students from staff, allowing only staff to login via the "staff login page".

The DN looks something like the following:

```
cn=USERNAME,ou=DEPT,ou=MAS,ou=LAN,o=UNI  <-- STAFF
cn=USERNAME,ou=DEPT,ou=STUDENT,ou=LAN,o=UNI <-- STUDENT
```

How can i go about filtering out ou=STUDENT or something to stop students from being able to login via the new Staff authentication script?

Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent student from being able to login via the new Staff authentication script, you can just change the base of you LDAP search. In spite of searching the UPN in the whole directoryn you searche the UPN from `ou=MAS,ou=LAN,o=UNI`.

With LDIFDE.EXE it would give :

ldifde -f c:\temp\user.ldf -d "ou=MAS,ou=LAN,o=UNI" -r "(userPrincipalName=login)"

So the search don't return anything if the user is a student.

On absolute LDAP it exists a filter syntax called **ExtensibleMatch** which allow you to do that, but it does work in AD.

Comment: Please excuse me, i am not very familiar with LDIFDE.exe, infact i have never used it. What your saying is that if change the base that im searching, so rather than searching "ou=LAN,o=UNI" , i could instead search "ou=MAS,ou=LAN,o=UNI" ?

Comment: At the moment, how do you obtain the DN of the person whih authentify ? I was supposing that in a form he was giving his login (userPrincipalName) and you make a search in the Directory to find the object. You can just start this search from a different place according to the login page.

Comment: Well currently, I am performing an Annonomous bind to the LDAP server with the username provided, then this returns the Distinguished name as shown above. Im then attempting to bind again with the returned DN and password. 
As i said though, im using this as the starting point:
     $dn="ou=LAN,o=UNI" ;  Could i just do ou=MAS,ou=LAN,o=UNI for my directory search?

Comment: Somthing I don't understand. If a bind is anonymous, it's not with a user ! So you perform an anonymous bind, then you search the user by is UPN ? Perhaps you can show your code, but yes I think you could just use ou=MAS,ou=LAN,o=UNI for your directory search?